# How pointer access operator -> works?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{

public:
    void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Having some fun"<<endl;
    }
};


class spointer
{
    myclass * mptr;
public:
    spointer(myclass * m)
    {
        mptr=m; 
    }

    myclass * operator->()
    {
        return mptr;
    }

};


int main() {
    // your code goes here

    spointer s(new myclass);

    s->fun();
    return 0;
}
```

when `s->fun()` is called in `main`, `s->` would return pointer to `myclass`, but then how `fun()` is called on `myclass` object pointed by the pointer?

---

edit : since `spointer::operator->` returns a pointer to `myclass`, why can one say `s->fun()`, instead of having to say `s->->fun()` or something

Comment: I'm sorry. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @JoelCornett I am guessing that, since `spointer::operator->` returns a pointer to `myclass`, why can one say `s->fun()`, instead of having to say `s->->fun()` or something. I think it is a valid question.

Comment: @JoelCornett 
juanchopanza, explained it correctly.

Comment: See the docs on "member access operators" here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: @q126y The basic answer is "it is required to work like that" because the whole point it to allow a user defined type to look like a pointer (at least as far as de-referencing is concerned)

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, you are right, but my pinky is weak, so I use `endl` in outside of production codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++11 standard says this about the overloaded `->` operator (13.5.6 "Overloading/Overloaded operators/Class member access"):

> An expression x->m is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object x of type T if `T::operator->()` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism

So the member access operator (`->`) is applied to the result of the overload implementation (resulting in something that acts like your `s->->fun()` comment).  This allows for the overload to operate 'naturally' when implementing smart pointers or pointer proxies.

Comment: this can also 'cascade' if `operator->` returns a class (not a pointer) that also have `operator->`